# Docker for windows10 run django fail: Can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django

I just start a sample django app. And use docker to run it. My docker image like:

```
FROM python:3.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  django:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

When I run `docker-compose up` command,it build successfully but failed in running `command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`,it complained `python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Is this a bug in docker for windows? Because I just follow the docs of docker [Quickstart: Docker Compose and Django](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/)

Thank for you help!

Comment: Did you complete the `Create a Django project` and the `Connect the database` part of the tutorial?

Comment: Yes. I create the django project and run it in a virtual python enviroment. It works well. I just use sqlite3 database.

Comment: So you did execute this line? `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .`

Comment: I change the service name 'web' to 'django'. And my project created in host rather than use 'docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject '.

Comment: I follow the official docs again and use `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` to create a new django project. Then I use `docker-compose up` and the comtainer run successfully. But i can't find the django project file in my current directory. In addition, can't we run a existed django project in a docker container?

Comment: How does your directory structure look like?

Comment: Now my directory only has three file:

D:\Users\zmrenwu\DockerDemo\docker-compose-example

`docker-compose.yml`

`Dockerfile`

`requirements.txt`

I don't know where is the new project structure. According to the official docs,it should show in current directory(.)

Answer (score 4):

I think you either missed this step: `docker-compose run web django-admin.py startproject composeexample .` or you're using a directory that isn't available to the Virtual Machine that is running docker.

If it works when you remove `volumes: .:/code` from the Compose file, then you know the issue is the volumes.

I believe by default only the users home directory is shared with the VM, so if you create a project outside of that tree, you won't have access to the files from volumes.

Comment: Thanks very much! This solve my problem. But if I can't mount the directory in host to VM, how could I share data between them? Is their any way to make it possible that VM can access the file on host?

Comment: Thank again! You save my life. According to your analysis I search the answer in [Docker official forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/5). The solution is we should enable host share the drive to docker container in docker settings.